# non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context issue when instantiating a new object

Tags: java, oop, this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class pwundublfive{
    public class Server{

        private ServerSocket socket;
        private int port;

        public Server(int port) throws IOException{
            socket = new ServerSocket(port);
            socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int port = 1234;
        Server obj = new Server(port); // <-- Error here
    }

}
```

I know this question has been posted numerous times, and I understand most of the answers that well you can't call a member method on a class. But I'm instantiating a new object, which calls its constructor?? Thanks :)

Comment: You are trying to reffer it, which you can't  do. That's all, no matter what is the use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Server` is a non-static inner class of `pwundublfive`, so you can either instanciate pwundublfive and than call `pwundublfiveInstance.Server(port)` or (which you should prefer) you can move your `Server` definition out of the other class into a separate file (called Server.java).

Answer (score 1):

The whole class `Server` is not `static`, so cannot be referenced in a static method.